# How to use a variable in another route in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route the creates a variable:

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res){
    var test = req.body.test //this is the var I want to use

    res.render('folder/ejs.ejs', {
        test: test})

    return test

  })
```

Then in another get route I am trying to instert the string into a url

```
app.get('/get', function(req, res) {
    axios.get('https://www.randomletters.com/1234/' + test)
    .then((response)=>{
    //.....
```

When I try to run this I am getting the error `ReferenceError: test is not defined`. How can I use the same var in different places?

Comment: You're defining `var test` inside of a function for your `/post` route, so it's only available there. You should send the value of `test` when you make your get request (eg: `/get?test=testValue`), then use something like `req.query.test` in your get callback to get the value

Comment: You can use `res.locals` to track per request state. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

Comment: @NickParsons It doesnt work. The get request has to be `/get`  because if it is anything else I get the error `Cannot GET /get`

Comment: @Joe Im very new to node.js and don't really know what I'm looking at/for...

Comment: @PythonIs2Hard what URL are you using when you get the `Cannot GET /get` error?